# JSF2 + Hibernate + Guice - What benefits is introduced by using DI (Guice)?

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, dependency-injection, guice

I'm currently preparing to start work on a new project to learn best practices on integrating JSF2 , Hibernate and DI (in form of Guice).

I've set my aim on JSF2 (myfaces) for presentation layer and Hibernate 4.1 for the Database layer (ORM).

Typically before i had ever used ORM i would settle for following Pattern of creating 
Backbean, BDI, BD,BO,DTO and DAO folder structure in the project where:

- The application backbeans methods go into Backbean Folder
- the Interfaces go into BDI folder
- Implementation of Interfaces go into BD folder
- classes in BO are used to Call upper layer DAO classes
- DAO classes is where all the JDBC stuff is done.

**Hibernate Question:**

With intention to integrate Hibernate do i need to get rid of DAO and make calls to HibernateDAO directly from BO? OR use DAO but instead of calling JDBC use Hibernate to interact with SQL?

**DI (Guice) question:**

I had previously been using classes such as "DeligateFactory" and "ServiceFactory" as a way of promoting lose coupling in my code so for example:

```
    //interface
    public Interface UserBDI {

        public User userAuth();
    }

    //implementation of the interface
    public class UserBD implements UserBDI {

        public UserBD() {};

        //do something here
        public User userAuth() {...};
    }


    //Deligate Factory
    public class DeligateFactory{

        public DeligateFactory(){}

        public static UserBDI CreateUserBD() {
            UserBDI bdObj = new UserBD();
            return bdObj;
        }
    }

    //some backbean
    public class homePage {
        public homePage(){}

        public authUSer(){
            userBD bdOBJ = DeligateFactory.CreateUserBD();

            User u = new User();
            u.setID("test");
            u.setPass("test");

            //validate
            u = bdObj.userAuth(u);

        }
    }
```

I understand the concept of DI is to eliminate tight coupling of interface implementation used in your code so if I am "integrating" DI into my project, am i simply getting rid of all the DeligateFactory/ServiceFactory methods and instead use DI to do this for me? Are there any other benefits?